# Call javascript functions of preloaded library from application

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a `WebView` where a some page was already loaded `webview.loadUrl(URL);`

Also there is an amount of javascript functions like a:

```
    function myFunction1() {// some code} 
    function myFunction2() {// some code}
    function myFunction3() {// some code}
```

I need to preload all functions onto `WebView` (when page is already loaded) and then execute them one by one from application as `webview.loadUrl("javascript: myFunction1()");` or `webview.loadUrl("javascript: myFunction3()");`

Is this possible to preload library instead of attaching js in the `html` code `<script src="js/myLibrary.js"></script>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult. Look, at first you should use `console.log`. It might help you to understand what happening during the script execution:

```
console.log('This message should appear as a debug message in Logcat.');
```

put this into `javascript` and you will get this message in the `LogCat`:

```
11-15 12:31:10.652: I/Web Console(16214): This message should appear as a debug message in Logcat.:1
```

Then, your question: you must load your javascript functions in the row:

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript: var globalVar; function init() {globalVar=1;}; function global() {init(); var gl = '2'; console.log(globalVar);}");
```

, here we have `init()` function that initializes `globalVar` and global, that init all vars and print result in logcat!

After preloading you could execute any functions:

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript: global();");
```

and you will see in logcat "1"! And that all!